# Using aesthetics with multiple layers in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am new to ggplot. I am trying to understand how to use ggplot. I am reading Wickham's book and still trying to wrap my head around how to use `aes()` function.

What's the difference between these two implementations of `aes()`:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy, colour = class)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

and

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = class)) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

Both of them print significantly different graphs. Any help? I am really stuck.

Comment: When you map aesthetics within the `aes` of `ggplot`, it is *global*.  This means the mapping are used by all other plotting layers in the plot unless you use the `inhert.aes` argument.  When you put them within a plotting layer like `geom_point`, they only affect that specific layer.

Comment: Before asking on SO, you should start by reading the relevant help text, i.e. `?aes`: "_Aesthetics supplied to `ggplot()` are used as defaults for every layer. you can override them, or supply different aesthetics for each layer_"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first one you are **mapping the aesthetics globally**, `ggplot` will try to map these aesthetics to all other geom_xyz() layers.

While in the latter case, you are mapping aesethics to a specific `ggplot` layer (in your case `geom_point()`)